# Calculate distances from one LatLng to many LatLng using Google Places API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, xamarin, google-places-api, google-distancematrix-api

I'm developing a small application to search a nearby location from current location.

I type something like "*New york*" in the textbox then the listview with filled with the list of matched nearby query "*New york*". I made this done by using Google Place Nearby search API. But I need one thing more is how to get a distance between my current location to every found nearby location. I can do this by calling `DistanceMatrix` API but it also means that I have to call `DistanceMatrixAPI` xxx times according to the found nearby location list

```
Text: "New york"

Distance | Name

0.1km    | Place 01

0.5km    | Place 02

...      | ...
```

I can absolutely get the distance by using Foursquare API...but anyway I need to work with Google

Any idea?

Thank you alot,

Comment: each Nearby result contains a lat/lng property, so you can use that to easily calculate a distance (direct path, not driving) from your current location using some simple trig.  Or, it appears that DistanceMatrix allows you to specify multiple locations in a single request.

Comment: @Jason thank you Jason. About the calculating by latlng is just about the flying path and it is useless for me. Anyway, I forgot that DistanceMatrix provides this!!!! One to many places